# Free actions of finite groups on products of even-dimensional spheres

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

Suppose a finite 2-group *G* acts freely on *X* = $\prod_{i=1}^k$ *S*$^{2n_i}$, a product of *k* even-dimensional spheres, *k* > 2. Is it possible for *G* to be non-abelian? What if we additionally assume that spheres in the product are equidimensional?

Some comments: The equality 2<sup>k</sup> = $\chi(X)$ = |G|$\chi(X/G)$ coming from the covering *X* $\to$ *X/G* ensures that a finite group acting freely on *X* is a 2-group and also answers the question for *k* = 1, 2. (Actually, for *k* = 1 this gives a proof of a classical theorem: the only group which can act freely on an even-dimensional sphere is the cyclic group of order 2. Does anyone know who is this result originally due to? Sorry for a question inside the question; perhaps someone can comment on this one.) Hence if one would like to construct a sort of "minimal" example, it should involve an action of either the quaternion group Q<sub>8</sub> or the dihedral group Dih<sub>4</sub> for *k* = 3. I thought about this a little bit, but I feel like I'm not comfortable enough with non-abelian groups.

I've stumbled across some papers where authors characterize arbitrary finite groups acting freely on *X* in terms of existence of particular representations, but explicit examples are given only in the abelian case.

Answer (score 5):

[Adem, Alejandro; Davis, James F. Topics in transformation groups.  Handbook of geometric topology,  1--54, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2002. MR1886667] mentions the fact that a finite $2$-group such that every element of order $2$ is central acts freely on $(S^{|G|/2-1})^k$, where $k$ is the rank of $G$, that is, the rank of the biggest subgroup of the form $(\mathbb Z_2)^{(r)}$: «The action is built by inducing up sign representations on $k$ elements of order $2$ which span the unique central elementary abelian subgroup of $G$ and then taking their product».

Using GAP I find a smallest non abelian example $G$ of order 32, which it describes as $(C_4\times C_2):C_4$.

Comment: I guess $C_2\times C_2\times Q_8$ is a simpler example...

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, but isn't S^{|G|/2-1} an odd-dimensional sphere? 